# Integration Rules: Why is the independent variable also a function?

Tags: calculus, integration

In my textbook, the integration rules are outlined like this:
[image]

There is a note at the end of the list of rules that says $u$ is a function of $x$. I don't understand why the independent variable $u$ of each integrand (each integrand is already a function) is also a function of another variable, namely $x$.

Comment: The idea is to take care of $u$ substitutions sort of "automatically". If you had $\int\cos(e^x)\,e^x\,dx,$ where $u=e^x$ and $du=e^x\,dx,$ you can invoke the first rule, you see.

Comment: Please reproduce those equations using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's torture on the eyes to read that blurriness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u=x$ then $du=dx$ and
$$\int \cos(u)du=\int \cos(x)dx=\sin(x)+C$$

But if, for example, $u=x^2$, then $du=2xdx$ and

$$\int \cos(x^2)d(x^2)=\sin(x^2)+C$$
and NOT

$$\int \cos(x^2)dx=\sin(x^2)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ is a function of $x$, then $du=u'(x)\,dx$ and the rule becomes

$$\int \cos(u)\,du=\int\cos(u(x))\,u'(x)\,dx=\sin(u(x))+C.$$